# Disable numbers and punctuation button on iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I have a UITextField that brings up the keyboard. I just want the user to input alphabets and not numbers or punctuation marks. How do I disable the numbers and punctuation key on the default keyboard that pops up.

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 0):

```
 Looking like you used the Default Keyboard....instead you can try to use:

 yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;  This might solve your problem.
```

& if this doesn't solve your problem other way, is:

---->  You need to create the Custom Keypad as per your requirement.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I tried not to go the custom route but perhaps I might have to.